# Search for Specific Records in Mongo DB

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, search

I am trying to fetch data from my course model where I have some data related to courses from MongoDB database. I want to implement a search mechanism so that only those documents should be fetched which are typed in the search bar.

Following is the server side code :
I am successful getting the key but unable to get valid records. Everytime I perform search operation I get all the records. Please Help.

```
  export const searchCourses = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log('SEARCH COURSES ==>');
    const { key } = req.params;
    console.log(key)
    
        const courses = await Course.find({
            $or: [
                {
                    title: { $regex: key, $options: 'i'}
                },
                {
                    description:{
                        $regex: key, $options:'$i'
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
)
        .populate('instructor', '_id name')
        .exec()

      console.log(courses)
    res.json(courses)

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question 100%, but to my understanding you are trying to filter results by a text input from the user? In that case you should use a useState, and send that to the server as a query. Here is a short example:

Client code:

```
const Context = React.createContect({
    async listData(query) {
      return await fetch("/api/search?" + new URLSearchParams(query));
    };
});

function SearchData(){
    const {listData} = useContext(Context);

    const [data, setData] = useState();
    const [dataQuery, setDataQuery] = useState();

    const { res } = async () => listGroups({ data }), [data]);

    <input onChange={(e) => setDataQuery(e.target.value)} />

    <button onClick={() => setData(dataQuery)} />
}
```

And server code:

```
router.get("/api/search", async (req, res) => {
    const [ data ] = req.query;
    const filter = {};
  
    if(data){
      filter.data = {$in: [data]};
    }
     
    const db = await database.collection(collection).find(filter)
      .map(({info} => ({info}))
      .toArray()
    
    res.json(db);
});
```

Not sure if this code exactly will work, but most of the functions are copied from own code, which works.